# QGIS - On Map, When Click On County It Pops Up More Info Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mapping, qgis

I am currently trying to create a state map with counties on it with some data behind it stating how many times our company been to that county within QGIS.  What I am trying to do is... When we click on the county, it will pop up a box with some county information and want to create it in QGIS.  Is there a way I can do this and how?  Trying to find tutorials on this.

Another question with QGIS...   I want to create either a drop down, navigation, or legend for each person.  When we check or choose their name, it shows how many times that person has been to that county.  Is there a way to do that on a live web map?

Please help and let me know of any tutorials to better under QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create different layers for the full company and then for each employee. In each layer, add a field with HTML text that provides the data you'd like to share for each county. You could have the polygons for each county filled to indicate that they had been visited, or you could leave them transparent until selected.

When you've done that, export your map using the qgis2web plugin and save it in the Leaflet format. Be sure to select the legend for each layer: This will let viewers filter between information on the full company and each individual.

This tutorial on the qgis2web plugin will help you figure just about all of this out: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

This StackOverflow question on the layers list should help too: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179403/how-to-add-legend-in-qgis2web-plugin-while-exporting-maps